# An excercise on Pagin and Page tables

Tags: virtual-memory, paging, page-replacement

I have an exercise on paging and page tables that I can't get my head around.

So the data is: my virtual addresses are 32 bits long, 1 page is 1 KiB, 1 PTE is 32 bits big and 1 page table is 1 page.

And then the prof asks how many page table levels are needed for this addressing.

so my solution would be:

- I can calculate for the last pagetable how many PTE there are per pageTable 1024/4 (4 bytes = 32 bits) => 256 so that's 8 bits I need for addressing this PTE.
  But for the parent levels I still can't calculate the size of the number of PDE (page directory entries) because I don't even have the size of the PDE yet.

So my question was with what I have given here I can't solve this question can I?

Comment: There is *page-in* as well as *paging*: please revise the title.